# Toolbar above keyboard doesn't hide when keyboard hides

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, inputaccessoryview

I've added a toolbar above keyboard to show Done button to dismiss keyboard. I've added it on my login screen. When keyboard is showing and I tap on saved Password icon to select saved password, keyboard hides but toolbar doesn't hide. Toolbar sits at the bottom of screen and then moves up with keyboard when keyboard shows again. It looks bad.

How do I fix it so that Toolbar doesn't show on it's own and shows/hide only with keyboard?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.emailTextField.addDoneButton(title: "Done", target: self, selector: #selector(tapDone(sender:)))
    self.passwordTextField.addDoneButton(title: "Done", target: self, selector: #selector(tapDone(sender:)))
}

@objc func tapDone(sender: Any) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

extension UITextField {
    
    // Add done button above keyboard
    func addDoneButton(title: String, target: Any, selector: Selector) {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 44.0)))
        
        let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: .plain, target: target, action: selector)
        barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.main, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red], for: [])
        toolBar.setItems([flexible, barButton], animated: false)
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd need the code for your "saved passwords" icon and flow to be able to reproduce your issue, with just this code it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I personally handle this in a different way as I'm not using any toolbar but custom views above the keyboard. As I want those views to animate and appear/disappear depending on the keyboard position, I first listen to keyboard changes:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardChanged(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

And then handle the keyboard current size and position manually here like so:

```
func keyboardChanged(_ userInfo: Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>?) {
    if let userInfo = userInfo {
        let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
        let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
        let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
        let animationCurve:UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
        if (endFrame?.origin.y)! >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
            // keyboard is masked, you can mask/move your toolbar here
        } else {
            // update your toolbar visibility and/or position/constraints here using 'endFrame?.size.height'
        }

        // animate your toolbar or any other view here:
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                delay: TimeInterval(0),
                options: animationCurve,
                animations: {
                     // animate what you need here
                     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                },
                completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So in your case I would create the toolbar first and constraint it to the bottom of the screen. Then I would use the code above to handle its position and visibility.

Then, whenever the keyboard position is updated, you can handle the toolbar (position and visibility) in the keyboard notification handler shown above.

Comment: Toolbar does hide and shows with keyboard under normal circumstances as it is inputAccessoryView and that's what it is suppose to do without manipulating it's hide/show. The problem only happens in the situation when I click on save password button. In this situation keyboard hides but not the toolbar which is weird. Tapping on forgot passord must be triggering something different that's why it doesn't hide toolbar with keyboard hide.

Answer (score -1):

Might not be a direct answer to this question but I highly suggest you to take a look at the IQKeyboardManager library. By default, it is a one liner keyboard handler but you can add your accessory views easily and it manages them well

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: I prefer not to use pods as they come and go. I had bad experience in using such pod which became inactive and I've to change a lot of code to fix it.

Comment: You can insall this without pod. Just download the source from git and copy the IQKeyboardManager folder into your project (as it said in the manual installation part). 

I see your reasoning by the way. I myself never run into this situation in 5 years with about 30 small-medium size projects if you are using big name libraries like Alamofire and IQKeyboardManager though. It can happen with smaller libraries but in this case, I usually just fork the source and fix the minor issues since it is still cheaper than creating a whole solution by yourself.